# How to tell if text fits in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write some vba code that monitors the OnChange event for a sheet and does some adjustment if text does not fit a cell. 
I.e. make the text smaller or wrap etc..

I know a can have Excel to automatically shrink the text and I know how to enable wrap in vba, but...

how do I check in vba whether the text fits in a cell to begin with?

Comment: i can only think of storing row heights, then enable wraptext, and check for changes in row height.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using THE "dirty" method - that's only one I know: force `AutoFit` and check new width/height.

However, we can't grantee that was chosen cell that forced new fit. So I opt by copying cell content to an empty worksheet.

That, of course, cause a lot of other problems, and more workarounds.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Fits(Target) Then
        'Notice that Target may have multiple cells!!!
    End If
End Sub

Function Fits(ByVal Range As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range, tmp_cell As Range, da As Boolean, su As Boolean
    'Stores current state and disables ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts
    su = Application.ScreenUpdating: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    da = Application.DisplayAlerts: Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Creates a new worksheet and uses first cell as temporary cell
    Set tmp_cell = Range.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets.Add.Cells(1, 1)
    'Assume fits by default
    Fits = True
    'Enumerate all cells in Range
    For Each cell In Range.Cells
        'Copy cell to temporary cell
        cell.Copy tmp_cell
        'Copy cell value to temporary cell, if formula was used
        If cell.HasFormula Then tmp_cell.Value = cell.Value
        'Checking depends on WrapText
        If cell.WrapText Then
            'Ensure temporary cell column is equal to original
            tmp_cell.ColumnWidth = cell.ColumnWidth
            tmp_cell.EntireRow.AutoFit 'Force fitting
            If tmp_cell.RowHeight > cell.RowHeight Then 'Cell doesn't fit!
                Fits = False
                Exit For 'Exit For loop (at least one cell doesn't fit)
            End If
        Else
            tmp_cell.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Force fitting
            If tmp_cell.ColumnWidth > cell.ColumnWidth Then 'Cell doesn't fit!
                Fits = False
                Exit For 'Exit For loop (at least one cell doesn't fit)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    tmp_cell.Worksheet.Delete 'Delete temporary Worksheet
    'Restore ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts state
    Application.DisplayAlerts = da
    Application.ScreenUpdating = su
End Function
```

Has solution got too complex, there may be some problems I didn't preview.

This won't work in read-only workbooks, however, cells in read-only workbooks don't change as well!

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty way which will not require you to check each and every cell.

I use this method to usually show all the data.

```
Sub Sample()
    With Thisworbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
        .ColumnWidth = 254.86 '<~~ Max Width
        .RowHeight = 409.5 '<~~ Max Height
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

I use this method if I want to wrap the text (If Applicable) and keep the row width constant

```
Sub Sample()
    With Thisworbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
        .ColumnWidth = 41.71 '<~~ Keep the column width constant
        .RowHeight = 409.5
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: This is not applicable for merged cells. For that there is a separate method.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion, but I'm not examining every cell, I'm monitoring OnChange, which gets fired (in my scenario) only on user input; not a very big load to keep up with. For this reason it's not the sort of answer I'm looking for right now.

Comment: You could put the above code in the worksheet change event and instead of `Cells`, just work with the relevant cell?

Comment: I would but the code is freely available on the web. Do a google search and you will get it :) @S.aad

Comment: Thank you very much. What about merged cells? Can you modify the answer to implement it?