# VB Code to check if text fits cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a tool on excel, I need to check if text fits the cell, if not I have to merge cells to fit text. cells are fixed I cannot use autofit or option.
Please suggest VB Code, thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if text fits in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732342/how-to-tell-if-text-fits-in-a-cell)

Comment: It sounds like you basically want to check the LEN of the text and if its greater than the max, merge the cell to the left? Show us a little code, what is the max ?

Comment: Do you mean: the column width is X points, how many characters can I fit before a second line is required?  (1) With a variable width font, this depends on the characters: "W" is a lot wider than "|". (2) There is no Excel or VBA routine such as `CheckWidth(Points, String)` of which I am aware that will return True if `String` will fit within a column of width `Points`.

Comment: The technique I use is to (a) pick a test cell to the right and below any cells being used, (b) set the width of the test cell's column to match the cell of interest, (c) copy the cell of interest to the test cell and (d) check the row height.

Answer (score 0):

Answered elsewhere, but this is a basic code that works. Autosize.

```
Sub merger()
Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Executive Weekly Summary")
If Not c Is Nothing Then
startrow = c.Row + 1
endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow).End(xlDown).Row - 1
End If
  '"A" & startrow & ":I" & endrow
OldWidth = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).ColumnWidth ' Save original width

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).EntireColumn.AutoFit
fitwidth = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth ' Get width required to fit entire text

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).ColumnWidth = OldWidth ' Restore original width

If OldWidth < fitwidth Then
Do Until OldWidth = fitwidth
    ActiveSheet.Range("").Merge
    endrow = endrow + 1

    OldWidth = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).ColumnWidth
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).EntireColumn.AutoFit
fitwidth = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow).ColumnWidth = OldWidth
Loop
End If
End Sub
```